# concatenate several grouping index into one

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, data.table, grouping

I am facing a problem where I must concatenate various grouping index into one. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(idx1 = c("1_1","1_1","1_2","1_3","1_4","1_4","1_5","1_6","1_6"),
                 idx2 = c("2_1","2_2","2_2","2_3","2_4","2_5","2_6","2_7","2_8"),
                 idx3 = c("3_1","3_1","3_2","3_3","3_3","3_5","3_6","3_7","3_8"))


  idx1 idx2 idx3
1  1_1  2_1  3_1
2  1_1  2_2  3_1
3  1_2  2_2  3_2
4  1_3  2_3  3_3
5  1_4  2_4  3_3
6  1_4  2_5  3_5
7  1_5  2_6  3_6
8  1_6  2_7  3_7
9  1_6  2_8  3_8
```

Each index indicates duplicated lines, detected with different methods. I want to create an index that concatenate the three. For example, line 1 and 2 are indicated to be the same by `idx1`, and line 2 and 3 by `idx2`, so line 1, 2 and 3 are the same and should have the same grouping index.

Line 4 and 5 have the same `idx3` grouping index and line 5 and 6 the same `idx1`, so they should have the same grouping index, different from lines 1, 2 and 3.

I did manage to write a loop to create the concatenated index:

```
df$I <- seq(df$idx1)
df$doublon_idx <- as.numeric(NA)
idx_cnt <- 1
for(i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  if(is.na(df[i,"doublon_idx"])){
    df[i,"doublon_idx" ] <- idx_cnt
    idx_cnt <- idx_cnt + 1
  }
  df[df$I != i & df$idx1 == df[i,]$idx1,"doublon_idx"] <- df[i,"doublon_idx"]
  df[df$I != i & df$idx2 == df[i,]$idx2,"doublon_idx"] <- df[i,"doublon_idx"]
  df[df$I != i & df$idx3 == df[i,]$idx3,"doublon_idx"] <- df[i,"doublon_idx"]
}
```

The (expected) output is:

```
  idx1 idx2 idx3 I doublon_idx
1  1_1  2_1  3_1 1           1
2  1_1  2_2  3_1 2           1
3  1_2  2_2  3_2 3           1
4  1_3  2_3  3_3 4           2
5  1_4  2_4  3_3 5           2
6  1_4  2_5  3_5 6           2
7  1_5  2_6  3_6 7           3
8  1_6  2_7  3_7 8           4
9  1_6  2_8  3_8 9           4
```

But I am not happy with it: it is not generalized, it uses a loop so it is slow when the table becomes big. I am sure there is a merging kind of way, or clever way to do so that I did not find. What is yours ? Can it be generalized to whatever number of grouping index ?

`dplyr` and `data.table` are welcome (though I prefer `data.table` if you can do both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how fast this will be on your actual dataset. Here is an approach combining `igraph` and `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, rn := .I]

#create edges and idx* are your vertices
DT <- rbindlist(list(
  df[, .(s=idx1, e=idx2, rn)],
  df[, .(s=idx1, e=idx3, rn)],
  df[, .(s=idx2, e=idx3, rn)]))

#find linked clusters
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(DT, directed=FALSE)
cl <- clusters(g)$membership))

#look up cluster for each vertex
DT[, g := cl[s]]

#look up grouping for each vertex
df[unique(DT, by="rn"), on=.(rn), doublon_idx := g]
```

output for e.g. 1:

```
   idx1 idx2 idx3 rn doublon_idx
1:  1_1  2_1  3_1  1           1
2:  1_1  2_2  3_1  2           1
3:  1_2  2_2  3_2  3           1
4:  1_3  2_3  3_3  4           2
5:  1_4  2_4  3_3  5           2
6:  1_4  2_5  3_5  6           2
7:  1_5  2_6  3_6  7           3
8:  1_6  2_7  3_7  8           4
9:  1_6  2_8  3_8  9           4
```

output for e.g. 2:

```
   idx1 idx2 idx3 rn doublon_idx
1:  1_1  2_1  3_1  1           1
2:  1_1  2_2  3_1  2           1
3:  1_2  2_2  3_2  3           1
4:  1_3  2_3  3_3  4           2
5:  1_4  2_4  3_3  5           2
6:  1_4  2_5  3_5  6           2
7:  1_5  2_6  3_6  7           3
8:  1_6  2_7  3_7  8           4
9:  1_6  2_8  3_8  9           4
```

Comment: your solution is faster, and is right. Comparing with your solution got me realizing that my loop solution was actually wrong. You helped a lot here